# Translation Golf XV - SPrako tranbia

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, euskera

Voy a hacer un poco de patria y poner un fragmento de una novela de un escritor de mi pueblo llamado [Unai Elorriaga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unai_Elorriaga_L%C3%B3pez_de_Letona). La novela está escrita originalmente en euskera y se titula *SPrako tranbia* (en español: Un tranvía en SP). Este es el fragmento que he elegido, casi al azar:

> Asko kostatzen zait orain sofatik altxatzea. Irentsi egiten nau sofak,
>   zaharra delako eta bigunegia, eta gero asko kostatzen zait handik
>   irtetea. Baina Marcos egoten da normalean nire ondoan eta lehenengo
>   bera altxatzen da eta gero niri laguntzen dit. Eta gero esaten du
>   goseak hilik egon behar duela sofak, ni bezalako gauza mingots bat
>   irensteko.

No sé si alguien sabrá euskera por aquí pero con [diccionarios](https://hiztegiak.elhuyar.eus/hiztegia) y [traductores](http://www.itzultzailea.euskadi.eus/traductor/portalExterno/text.do) se puede uno hacer una idea y además tenemos la traducción que hizo el propio autor para la versión en español:

> Ahora me cuesta mucho levantarme del sofá. Me traga el sofá, porque es
>  viejo y es blando, y después me cuesta mucho salir de allí. Pero
>  últimamente suele estar Marcos, y primero se levanta él y luego me
>  ayuda a mí. Y luego me dice que el sofá tiene que estar muerto de
>  hambre para tragarse una cosa tan amarga como yo.

La cosa va como siempre, conseguir el mínimo número de caracteres manteniendo el sentido del original.

Para aquellos que no sepan euskera, que será la mayoría :), he hecho mi propia traducción en inglés ya que no he encontrado ninguna por la red. Me han ayudado un poco y creo que es correcta pero si veis algún fallo corregidlo:

> Now I can hardly get up from the sofa. The sofa swallows me, because
>   it is old and too soft, and then I can hardly get out of there. But
>   normally Marcos is with me, and first he stands up and then he helps me.
>   And then he tells me that the sofa must be starving to swallow a thing as
>   bitter as me.

---

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

---

@walen gana esta edición en el último momento. Tras toda la semana en solitario apareció @fedorqui a punto de vencer el plazo y se lo puso difícil.

Como manda la tradición el ganador tiene dos días para proponer un nuevo reto, pasado ese plazo cualquiera puede hacerlo.

Comment: Qué libro tan fantástico, lo leí hace mucho.

Comment: Parece un reto interesante, el euskera me parece un idioma espectacular, por su sonoridad, complejidad y por su condición de lengua única en el mundo. El problema es que acabo de empezar la segunda parte de mis vacaciones en las que me he quedado sin wifi y me va a resultar más complicado responder (y más si tengo que ir mirando diccionarios de euskera). O eso o miro la traducción al español y trato de resumirla. A ver si esta edición puede contar con otros participantes...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo en el último juego solo estuvimos nosotros dos, espero que se apunte alguien más si tú fallas esta vez. En este reto es más probable que se opte por resumir la traducción directamente, sé que es complicado incluso con diccionario por los sufijos, (quien no los conoce no sabrá cual el la palabra original) y los traductores no son muy buenos en general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### <strike>152</strike> 126 caracteres

> Apenas puedo [alzarme](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=alzar) del sofá: es viejo, [fofo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=fofo) y me come; cuesta salir. Mas Marcos me acompaña: se alza él, luego a mí. «Mucha hambre tiene para comerte, amargo», dice.

He reordenado la última frase un poco, pero creo que se entiende bien el sentido.
Uso "me acompaña" como presente habitual.

Comment: Supongo que *usa estar conmigo* sería algo así como *acostumbra a estar conmigo* ¿no? Es que suena un poco raro. ¿Y lo de *amarga* del final se lo dice al narrador? Si es así sería *amargo*.

Comment: Perfecto. Lo has reducido mucho a la primera, va a estar complicado superarlo

Comment: Por fin un poco de competición, en el último minuto como debe ser :)

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>179 166</s> 151 caracteres

> Ya apenas puedo [auparme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4On8E7d) del sofá: viejo y blando, me traga; ¡cuesta salir de él! Ahora me ayuda Marcos: se aúpa él, luego a mí, acaba con un "Tan amargo como eres, ¡cuánto hambre tendrá para comerte!".

Como me gusta este libro...

Comment: *aupar* en lugar de *auparme* me suena raro pero puede que sea correcto. Con lo que si tengo muchas dudas es con la expresión *a últimas*, en el DRAE aparece solo en masculino ya que se refiere a los últimos días, además necesitamos un período de tiempo concreto (semana, mes, etc) y aquí no lo hay ni se intuye.

Comment: Por otra parte has sido algo más fiel que @walen en el significado original de algunas frases y por eso tienes mas caracteres, aún así, buen trabajo!

Comment: @blonfu tienes razón, _aupar_ debía ser pronominal. Corregido

Comment: @blonfu en cuanto _a últimas_, uso lo que DLE menciona de _En los últimos días del período de tiempo que se indica **o se sobrentiende**_. Entiendo que aquí el hecho de que sean semanas, meses o años es irrelevante, los tiempos para alguien aquejado de esta enfermedad son etéreos cuanto menos.

Comment: No lo sé, a mi me parece que *a últimos* siempre implica un tiempo concreto aunque no se diga, por ejemplo: *cobro a últimos* se sobreentiende que es a últimos de mes. No lo veo como sustituto de últimamente.

Comment: @blonfu pensé en decir directamente _ahora_, pero no sé si es demasiada licencia. Sea como fuere, he hecho algún requiebro para bajar a 166 caracteres. walen lo puso difícil.

Comment: Es dificil poner el límite de hasta donde permitir las licencias ¿en que momento se empieza a perder el verdadero significado? Con algunas frases no lo tengo muy claro pero tú inténtalo como te parezca y luego ya se discute.

Comment: @blonfu intentémoslo.

Comment: Es curioso que hayas usado *Ahora me ayuda Marcos*, en castellano cambia un poco el sentido pero en euskera *ayudar* y *acompañar* son la misma palabra: *lagundu*

Answer (score 3):

#### BONUS -  Fuera de concurso

Como era mi juego y no podía participar me entretuve un poco haciendo una traducción en una especie de jerga. Conozco gente que habla más o menos así:

**153 caracteres**

> Es chungo salir del sofá. Me traga porque es viejo y blandurrio, y
> luego a ver quién sale. Ese Marcos ahí, sale: *¡flop!*, y me ayuda. Me
> narra que ese sofá está canino para jalarse un tío amargo como yo.